# Add borders with Range.Paste Method

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

I'm trying to add borders to a table that I have copied to word from excel. I haven't defined the table name but using the Range.Paste method, does anyone know how to add borders to the table-Below is the code that I am using

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Participants - C").Range("C7:D13").Copy
docWord.Bookmarks("TransParties").Range.Paste
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```vb
Sub test()

'add your code, e.g. set docWord etc. here

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Participants - C").Range("C7:D13").Copy

With docWord.Bookmarks("TransParties").Range
    .Paste
    
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Set tbl = .Tables(1)
    
    addBorders tbl
End With

End Sub

Private Sub addBorders(tbl As Word.Table)
Dim arrBorders As Variant

'WdBorderType
 arrBorders = Array( _
    wdBorderBottom, _
    wdBorderTop, _
    wdBorderLeft, _
    wdBorderRight, _
    wdBorderVertical, _
    wdBorderHorizontal _
    )
    
Dim b As Long
With tbl.Borders
    For b = LBound(arrBorders) To UBound(arrBorders)
        With .Item(arrBorders(b))
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
            .color = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

In Word VBA you have to set each border individually :-(

Comment: It throws an error for addBorders Sub /Function not defined

Comment: You have to either put both Subs in the same module - or declare `addBorders` as `Public` instead of `Private`.

Comment: I would like to keep it in the same command, its difficult to again open the document and add borders, Is there anyway to do it in the same command like copying the data and adding borders?

Comment: I don't understand: you can put the `addBorders`-sub directly below the sub where you paste do the paste

Comment: Let me try it again, now its throwing an error as h_Word Variable not defined.

Comment: Sorry - my fault - that's from testing - I adjust the code

Comment: Then what should I replace it with to refer to the active word document.

Comment: In your code (within your question) your are referriing to docWord - where do you get that from?

Comment: As you have suggested to add another subroutine, I have to again declare the variable earlier for me it was as follows_ Set docword= ObjWord.Documents.Open("file path"), now the file is already open right now.

Comment: you don't need a new docWord when passing tbl to addBorders ...

Comment: Read about using the `With`-statement and calling subs - then you should understand why this is working.

Comment: This isnt working for me, it is creating additional tables with border before and after the existing table. Is there a provision to share screenshots or attach images?