# Adding borders in word with Range.Paste Method

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have been looking to add borders to a word table that I am copying from an excel file. Below is the code that I am using-
I am looking to add borders to this table in the same subroutine, can anyone please help me with this. Thanks

```vb
Dim ObjWord As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
ObjWord.Visible = True
Dim docWord As Object
Dim oCC As ContentControl
ObjWord.Activate

Set docWord = ObjWord.Documents.Open(Filename:="\\\CPFSPRDAPAWSE01\userdata$\NTiwari\Desktop\Automations\abc Memo.docx", ReadOnly:=False)
docWord.Activate
For Each oCC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls

        Select Case oCC.Title
            Case "IssuerName" 'This is the Title being referenced for CC in Word
                oCC.Range.Text = "abc" & Right(xyz, 3) & " pqr" 'This is the named cell being referenced in excel
            Case "CommitteeType"
                     oCC.LockContents = False
                     oCC.DropdownListEntries(2).Select
                     oCC.LockContents = True
            Case "CommitteeDate"
                    oCC.Range.Text = Date
            Case "Methodology"
                oCC.Range.Text = "fgs"
            Case "Methodology2"
                oCC.Range.Text = "NA"
            Case "ESGYesNo"
                oCC.DropdownListEntries(1).Select
            Case "ESGComments"
                oCC.DropdownListEntries(1).Select
            Case "FinancialObsYesNo"
                oCC.DropdownListEntries(1).Select
             Case "ContractualPayObsYesNo"
                oCC.DropdownListEntries(1).Select
            Case "DataChecksYesNo"
                oCC.DropdownListEntries(1).Select
            Case "DataCheckResult"
                oCC.DropdownListEntries(1).Select
            Case "FinancialObsYesNo"
                oCC.DropdownListEntries(1).Select
             Case "RatingAction"
                oCC.DropdownListEntries(2).Select
             Case "BasisForAction"
                oCC.Range.Text = "text"

         End Select
    Next oCC

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Participants - C").Range("C7:D13").Copy
docWord.Bookmarks("TransParties").Range.Paste
docWord.SaveAs "\\CPFSPRDAPAWSE01\userdata$\NTiwari\Desktop\Automations\abc Docs\" & "DealName " & " abc Memo.docx"

docWord.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: If you show us the whole code - I show you where to call the `addBorders`-sub from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75088386/16578424)

Comment: Pls check it now in the main question

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. You have already been given an answer in your other question. If there is something you do not understand about it then ask for clarification there.

Comment: I asked for it but I did not hear anything so I posted it again with the full code now.